# Could not load type 'NavigateWebApp.Global'

Tags: asp.net, .net

Recently  we have moved our project to web app and everything is good but suddenly I do not  know when I am trying to debug my application its showing me the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'NavigateWebApp.Global'.

Source Error: 

Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="NavigateWebApp.Global" Language="C#" %>


Source File: /global.asax    Line: 1 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4971; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4971
```

I am sure that there are no build errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by your `'NavigateWebApp.Global'` class/namespace not being available in the location you've specified.

Check where you define this and ensure it's accessible to the `Global.asax` page.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is your `Global.asax` file is referencing a class which no longer exists (or at least at the location you have specified). Simple fix is to update the `Inherits` attribute with the fully qualified path to your `Global.asax` class name (which you will find in the `Global.asax.cs` file).

Comment: Thanks for your reply..Even that was the one which was on my mind when I posted but It did not work for me and when I was trying to  browse for more solutions I came across a new scenario which was some thing to my IIS ....so do you have any idea how IIS is dragged in to the picture...